# Configure which program to use as terminal

Tags: linux, xdg

I have created a `neovim.desktop` file for a (terminal) application that looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Neovim
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;...
Exec=nvim -f %F
Type=Application
Terminal=true
```

As you can see, it requests to being run within a terminal window. This works perfectly find, however it always opens `xterm`. Now the question is: Where on my system is it configured which terminal to use for such applications?

Is this desktop-dependent? If so: Where is it in GNOME? Where (so this is useful for other people as well) is it in KDE?

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard location for this; it depends on the desktop environment.

---

In GNOME 3, this is stored in dconf/GSettings:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal
org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'gnome-terminal'
org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg '-x'

$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec xterm
```

The same for Cinnamon, except under the `org.cinnamon.desktop.⋯` domain.

---

GNOME 2 used to keep this in GConf:

```
$ gconftool-2 -R /desktop/gnome/applications/terminal
 exec = gnome-terminal
 exec_arg = -x

$ gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/applications/terminal/exec -t string xterm
```

Answer (score 2):

After the suggestions from grawity did not work out as expected, I searched a bit further, and found that GLIB has the list of terminal emulators hardcoded. So it does not reflect any settings when an application is launched using it's functionality.

The corresponding source can be found here: https://github.com/frida/glib/blob/master/gio/gdesktopappinfo.c#L2467 - Search for "gnome-terminal" in that file if the line number does not match anymore.

So - if you use one of the terminals in that list, uninstall the ones higher up on that list. If you use another one, create a script named `xterm` in `/usr/local/bin` and have it call your terminal. This is what I've done now:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec sakura "$@"
```